# grails change application url dynamically for different controllers

Tags: java, redirect, grails, spring-security

Grails 2.4.4

Guys, I am working on an grails application and I have a requirement where I have to render pages from same application into different host URL's

For example:

```
Home page url (pre-login) should be www.mydomain.com 
Home page url (post-login) should be home.mydomain.com 
Login page url should be login.mydomain.com
Register page url should be register.mydomain.com
and Rest pages url should be inner.mydomain.com
```

All the above urls are added as an alias in `tomcat -> server.xml` file and is pointing to same application directory.

I have created a static method which according to controller and action determines and return the host url. I am using this method from grails filter.

I then just replace the old host url with the new generated one and then issue a normal redirect url.

The problem I am facing here is, if the app is not loggedin, than all works well. But when I try to login from host url `login.mydomain.com`, then spring security creates session only for `login.mydomain.com`. Session is not created for `home.mydomain.com` and hence I am not redirected to post-login `home.mydomain.com` but instead redirected back to pre-login `www.mydomain.com`

So, can you someone tell me what is the correct way to achieve this. Can I change my host url without effecting my locale, cookies and session? Can Spring security authenticate multiple host at the same time?
Is there any java way to do this?

Any other suggestions?

Please let me know if more inputs are needed

Comment: @burtbeckwith please help

Comment: @tim_yates any suggestions??